# How to make overflow-y: scroll account for border size

Tags: html, css

I would like to make ul's overflow account for the borders of div it is contained in.

I have tried adding padding with the same px measurement as border tag.

```
.resizable {
  background: black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%; /* Magic to turn square into circle. */
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #4286f4;
  position: absolute;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer.top-left {
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer.top-right {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer.bottom-left {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer.bottom-right {
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}

#npc_events {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#npc_events li {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```
        <body>
            <div id='div_npc_chat' class='resizable'>
                <div class='resizers'>
                    <div class='resizer top-left'></div>
                    <div class='resizer top-right'></div>
                    <div class='resizer bottom-left'></div>
                    <div class='resizer bottom-right'></div>

                    <div class="chat-wrapper">
                        <form id="npc_chat-form">
                            <input id="npc_chat" autocomplete="off" title="chat"/>
                            <button id="npc_say">Say</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="npc_events"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

I expected the text, which is `<li>` elements of `<ul>` contained in `<div>` to not appear above div's blue borders, but I got this:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/401030271417188355/613446713629343756/unknown.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your list is overflowing (or going out of the div/appearing on top of the line) is due to the fact that you have the tag #npc_events set to 100% height and this is not accounting for the input bar (chat-wrapper div).

One solution would be to add a padding to .resizers class and calculating the height of the class .chat-wrapper div, from there you can add the following to the #npc_events div.

```
height: calc(100% - (height of chat-wrapper));
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend setting the height of the chat-wrapper to a certain percentage of the wrapper div (.resizers) and the remaining to the list. For example:

```
.resizers {padding: 10px;}
.chat-wrapper {height: 20%;}
#npc_events {height: 80%;}
```

This would get you the desired result.